# vis js how to spread nodes evanly on all canvas and avoid text overlapping?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vis.js

I am using [vue-vis-network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-vis-network) as my graph component.

this library relly on the [Vis Js](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/) core library

and all configuration should be supported

I want to spread nodes evenly on all canvas and to avoid the text overlapping.

this is how it looks with the current options:

[image]

this is the current options that I use:

```
  options: {
    physics: {
      barnesHut: {
        springLength: 1000,
        springConstant: 1,
        avoidOverlap: 1
      }
    },
    nodes: {
      shape: 'dot',
      font: {
        size: 12
      }
    },
  },
```

il be happy for guidance on how to achieve my 2 main goals :

1. spread the nodes on all canvas
2. avoid node and text overlapping ( "correlation" and "conspiracy theory" as shown in the image)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 physics: {
        barnesHut: {
            "gravitationalConstant": -3900,
            "centralGravity": 0
        },
        minVelocity: 1
    }
```

Try the above options and check if you achieve your requirement.

Comment: Why does this achieve the requirements?   What do these parameters accomplish either separately or together?

Comment: @Boyd 
gravitationalConstant - Gravity attracts. We like repulsion. So the value is negative. If you want the repulsion to be stronger, decrease the value (so -10000, -50000).

centralGravity - There is a central gravity attractor to pull the entire network back to the center.

minVelocity - Once the minimum velocity is reached for all nodes, we assume the network has been stabilized and the simulation stops.